# Azure notification hub limit for devices across multiple Hubs

Tags: azure, push-notification, azure-notificationhub

We have a use-case where we want to register the same Mobile device to multiple Hubs within the same namespace using different tags.For example if I have namespace called N with Hubs H1 and H2 and a device D and I want to

- Register Device D with H1 hub using tag T1 and with H2 hub with tag T2, would this be counted twice in the 10M device limit for the namespace or only once ?
  https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/

Comment: [What is the price model for Notification Hubs?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-push-notification-faq#what-is-the-price-model-for-notification-hubs-) and [Configuring hubs and Namespaces](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/193190/configuring-hubs-and-namespaces.html)

Comment: I cant find the scenarios to be similar as mine. My question is whether a single device registered with multiple hubs in the same namespace would be counted as one device or multiple devices ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would count twice, because there would be two unique registration ids.
As its mentioned the [linked document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/notification-hubs/) you provided.

[image]